# why the same inline variable with static storage duration constructs and destructs twice when include in two translate units compiled by vs2017

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, c++17, language-lawyer

"test.hpp" is defined as below:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
class test{
public:
  test(){
   std::cout<<"constructor"<<std::endl;
  }
  ~test(){
   std::cout<<"destructor"<<std::endl;
  }
};
class test_content{
public:
  inline static test test_gobal;
};
```

"a.cpp" is defined as below:

```cpp
#include "test.hpp"
```

"b.cpp" is defined as below:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "test.hpp"
int main(){

}
```

Like the above, include "test.hpp" in two translate units,Compile these code by vs2017 version 15.9.21,then the outcome will print "constructor" and "destructor" twice,Is there any quote talk about how construct or destruct inline variable when it is included in more than one translate unit?I haven't found these qoutes about this.or Is it a vs2017 bug,whatever what's the quotes about this?

Comment: @LanguageLawyer paging

Comment: @cigien Hi,I have modified content of  "test.hpp" in this question.

Comment: A complete example means a program.

Comment: @einpoklum Modified the question

Comment: According to the link: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/226484/vc2017-1564-inline-variable-in-header-multiple-con.html. 
It seems a issue in vs2017, and a fix for this issue has been released in vs2019.

Answer (score 0):

Well, first, it's not clear to me you can even *use* `std::cout` in a constructor executed as part of static initialization. But this aside - both clang and gcc, when given this program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
struct test {
  test() { printf("ctor\n"); }
  ~test(){ printf("dtor\n"); }
};
class test_content{
public:
  inline static test test_gobal;
};

int main() {}
```

Compile the code to execute the constructor and the destructor exactly once each ([see this on GodBolt](https://godbolt.org/z/cZQFdg)). So what you're seeing is probably an MSVC issue.

Comment: yes,vs2019 is ok,vs2017 is wrong,what's the quote in the standard about this?

Comment: @jackX: I'm not well-versed in the standard. But an object of static storage duration is constructed once and destructed once, and an inline static variable is just that.